# Nested Anova with count (frequency) data

Tags: anova, count-data, nested-data, fishers-exact-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a data set that includes count data (# of times a behavior is observed, 4 total behaviors) that has been recorded at 2 research sites, and on multiple individuals at each site. I'm looking for a way to tell if a) individuals within a site differ significantly in usage of these behaviors, and b) if the two sites differ in overall usage of the behaviors.

I have pooled all the individuals and performed a Fisher's Exact Test between sites, but this is unsatisfying because some individuals clearly bias the overall data (i.e. use a disproportionate amount of a certain behavior in some individuals).

So it seems to me that I need a Nested ANOVA with Site as a Fixed Factor, Individual as a Random sub-factor. The number of counts per individual is also not constant, and is sometimes <5, so a non-parametric test is almost certainly needed. Can a Kruskal-Wallace test be used for a Nested effect with count data? Also any tips for implementation in R would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,